# EOS signatures vs Ethereum signatures

Tags: smart-contract, ecc

So I'm trying to find a way to sign a message with a certain private key, and then to be able to recover it's corresponding public key/address on both Ethereum and EOS. The thing is I'm having some trouble understanding how signatures are constructed in EOS. How are EOS's signatures different than Ethereum's other than:

1. being base58 encoded, rather than a hexadecimal.
2. being prefixed with 'SIG_K1_'

So far I've tried recovering public keys using Ethereum's ecrecover function, and using this piece of code on EOS:

```
ACTION DaVerifier::ecverify(std::string data, const capi_signature &sig)
{
    capi_checksum256 digest;
    sha256(&data[0], data.size(), &digest);
    uint8_t pub[34];
    auto res = recover_key(&digest, (char *)&sig, sizeof(sig), (char*)pub, 34);
    printhex(pub, sizeof(pub));
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

In EOS a signature consists of the 'SIG' prefix, follwing the part that defines which curve algorithm was used (R1 or K1), follwing the SHA256 hash encoded with base58.

Take a look at https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc, it contains all the neccessary cryptographic functions you need.